# Retrieving and storing data from pls file in PHP

Tags: php, regex, stream, store

I need to create a series of regular expressions to get data out of a pls file in PHP (a language I've only just started learning).

The file will output data similar to this:

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=1
File1=http://203.150.225.71:8000
Title1=(#1 - 3687/5000) Example Radio Station 
Length1=-1
Version=2
```

I need to retrieve and store the location of the stream with the port number included as well as the title.

I need advice on the best way to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHPs buit in function [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to parse the ini formatted file.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for those answers. I tried the following code:     $ini_array = parse_ini_file("tunein-station.pls");
echo $ini_array['playlist']['File1']; This just gives me a warning followed by the entire contents of the file. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: @RyanDreggs, ok, I'll RTFM for you: `parse_ini_file("tunein-station.pls", true)`. The instructions on the linked page are clear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an INI file to me. Maybe Zend_Config_Ini would be a useful way to parse it..

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html

Comment: Or stick to native PHP, and use Qtax's answer +1